# C code works in Visual Studio 2013, but does not in 2017?

Tags: c, compilation, visual-studio-2017

Today I wrote a code at the university on `VS 2013` and it worked. I sent it to myself through email to try at home. Its not working on `VS 2017`. Fortunately I have `VS 2013` and it does work on it. Why is this happening?
Here is the part of the code that fails on `VS 2017`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct{
    char name[50];
    char pos[50];
    double sel[12];
    double annpay;
}sluj;

typedef struct{
    int num;
    sluj per[100];
}firma;

firma f;

int main(){

    int i, j;

    do{
        printf("Enter number of employees\n");
        scanf("%d", &f.num);
    } while (f.num < 1 || f.num > 100);

    for (i = 0; i < f.num; i++){
        printf("Enter the name of employee:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(f.per[i].name, 50, stdin); //it acts like this row doesnt exist 
                                 //and prints the text below
        printf("Enter the position of employee:\n");
        fgets(f.per[i].pos, 50, stdin);  //basiclly the same thing as above, but on different
                                 //structure member (both are defined char) 
                                 //and it works here!

        for (j = 0; j < 12; j++){
            printf("Enter salary for %d month\n", j+1);
            scanf("%lf", &f.per[i].sel[j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < f.num; i++){
        f.per[i].annpay = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < 12; j++){
            f.per[i].annpay += f.per[i].sel[j];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < f.num; i++){
        if (f.per[i].annpay > 6000){
            printf("\n%s %lf", f.per[i].name, f.per[i].annpay);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't think the problem is with `fflush`, because it doesn't work even without it.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior (`fflush` is a write operation, but `stdin` is an input stream).

Comment: @melpomene It's well defined on MSVC.

Comment: @dbush - MS has made significant changes in VS2017. I'm iffy on the details, but the OP's code is not well-defined.

Comment: Hm. I think the duplicate is not necessarily is a duplicate... There are many possible reasons for UB here

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Should it be reopened and then closed as needing a [mcve]?

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, that's what I would vote for :) Not sure it worth reopening though..

Comment: @JustSteve - We can easily test if that's the problematic line. Go to your project options and change the /permissive options from false to true. Does it make any difference at all?

Comment: @StoryTeller doesnt fix it

Comment: Alright. If you edit the post to contain a proper [mcve], I'll undo my close vote.

Comment: @StoryTeller Edited.

Comment: https://www.go4expert.com/articles/solution-using-scanf-fgets-c-t27148/

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` and `fgets()` do not work well together. `scanf()` reads number of employes and the submitting `\n` is still buffered and will be given to `fgets()`. The `fflush()` does not work on pipes.

E.g. with linux and glibc you get the same behavior

```
$ ltrace ./a.out  > /dev/null 
puts("Enter number of employees")                             = 26
__isoc99_scanf(2
"%d", 6295680)                                 = 1
fflush(0x7f7c6811c9e0)                                        = 0
puts("Enter the name of employee:")                           = 28
fgets("\n", 50, 0x7f7c6811c9e0)                               = 0x601088
puts("Enter the position of employee:")                       = 32
```

There is no good way to combine both functions; Use e.g. `fgets()` to read the number of employees into a string and convert this later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that `scanf()` leaves the `'\n'` as the artifact in the `stdin`. 
Mixing  `scanf()` and  `fgets()` is unwise. 
Your program with `scanf()` has no protection for entering wrong input. It would hang if letters are entered as number of employees.

The use of `fflush()` will not help.

`fflush()` is typically used for `output` stream only. Its purpose is to clear (or flush) the output buffer and move the buffered data to console (in case of `stdout`) or disk (in case of file output stream).

As per C standard, it is undefined behavior to use `fflush(stdin)`.

However, on some compilers like `VS2013` it "works". That has been changed in `VS2017`.

The quick fix for leftover `'\n'`  is as follows:

```
do{
    printf("Enter number of employees\n");
    scanf("%d", &(f.num));
} while (f.num < 1 || f.num > 100);

int c;
c = getchar();
if(c == EOF)
    return -1; // END OF PROGRAM

if (c!='\n')
    ungetc(c, stdin);
```

Comment: @JustSteve  It would "work" on VS2013, but as per C standard, it is undefined behavior to use `fflush(stdin).`  The VS2017  behaviour is in line with  the current `gcc`.